# gnuplot : parametric equation, positive variable OK, negative variable confusing

Tags: gnuplot, parametric-equations

Using gnuplot (5.4 patchlevel 2 - see script below), I plotted the parametric equation from this Wikipedia entry:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclocycloid

If the given epicycloid variables R=3, r=1, d=0.5 are used (see below), the result matches that on the Wikipedia page. However, using the hypotrochoid variables R=5, r=-3, d=5 produces a plot that does not match the example (it should be a five-fold symmetric star shape). That it is a circle is suggestive of a technical misunderstanding.

script :

```
reset
# hypotrochoid:
R=5 ; r=(-3) ; d=5
# epicycloid:
# R=3 ; r=1 ; d=(0.5)
x(t) = (R + r) * cos(t) - d * cos( ( ( R + r ) / ( r )  ) * t )
y(t) = (R + r) * sin(t) - d * sin( ( ( R + r ) / ( r )  ) * t )
set parametric
set size square
plot x(t),y(t)
```

I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how gnuplot uses the values, how users provide them, or with parametric plotting. I have tried a number of things to explore this, such as :

-adding or removing parentheses

-expressing -3 as -3.0 (interesting, as it produces a fish-like trace)

-incrementally increasing or decreasing the values

-fractions v. decimals

- rewriting the expression with negative signs
- putting the negative sign in the expression and changing the expression to positive - this is interesting, but is not matching the expectations.

... generally, the negative value produces results that are unexpected. I have managed to get nice drawings, but they are not producing the result on Wikipedia. I cannot tell if it is the expression, the value, or both - perhaps the Wikipedia article needs more information, or it is a mathematics question. It has me running in... circles.

pos-answer follow-up : notice - the range is unspecified, and gnuplot dutifully produces a plot to, apparently, the default of 2*pi - while clearly, the Wikipedia entry shows the plot needs to be run for 3 cycles to see the symmetric pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "everlasting pitfall" of gnuplot's integer division.
Make your input parameters floating point values and everything should be fine.

**Script:**

```
### parametric plot
reset session

x(t) = (R + r)*cos(t) - d*cos((R + r)/r*t)
y(t) = (R + r)*sin(t) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t)
set parametric
set size ratio -1
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 1,2

    # epicycloid:
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    set trange[0:2*pi]
    plot x(t),y(t) w l lw 2 lc "red"

    # hypotrochoid:
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    set trange[0:6*pi]
    plot x(t),y(t) w l lw 2 lc "blue"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Just for completeness: rotating the graph by 90°, by exchanging `cos()` and `sin()` and changing the sign on `y(t)`. And keeping the graph a square by same x- and y-range.

**Script:**

```
### parametric plot
reset session

x(t) =  (R + r)*sin(t) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t)
y(t) = -(R + r)*cos(t) + d*cos((R + r)/r*t)

set parametric
set size ratio -1
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 1,2

    # epicycloid:
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    set xrange[-6:6]
    set yrange[-6:6]
    set trange[0:2*pi]
    plot x(t),y(t) w l lw 2 lc "red"

    # hypotrochoid:
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    set xrange[-8:8]
    set yrange[-8:8]
    set trange[0:6*pi]
    plot x(t),y(t) w l lw 2 lc "blue"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Excellent - but I apologize - my error was not setting the range to go beyond what I assume is the default : 2*pi. Thanks.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange glad to hear. Actually, you might want to set `set size ratio -1` such that x and y have the same scale (i.e. a square looks like a square), not just a square graph.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange see updated answer with `ratio -1`. The x,y grid lines form squares, but the graph itself is not necessarily a square. But you can enforce it by setting the same range for x and y.

Comment: a tech note for users : pay attention to the terminal window if running this in a script - unless the ```unset multiplot``` is given in the script, there will be confusion.  For the record, multiplot produced postscript, pngcairo, and svg output ok (I was confused before but it seems I got it to work). I took care to put the terminal and output above the ```plot``` and ```set multiplot``` lines in the script. HTH.

Comment: I hope one last question : should ```rotate=90``` work in multiplot mode to turn each image by 90 degrees, as I can see from the demo here : http://gnuplot.info/demo/image2.html - it would be handy to turn the images, as if turning each of them by hand if they were printed out on paper - and it seems ```rotate``` should do it, and not by recomputing the function itself or swapping axes - or should this be a separate question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange I usually don't add a specific terminal on purpose to my examples, because every user might have a different default terminal.
If you start a `set multiplot` environment you should also end it with `unset multiplot`. Of course, `set terminal <whatever>` has to come before `multiplot` and `plot`. Furthermore, if you select a terminal which writes to a file, e.g. `pngcairo`, `pdfcairo`, etc. and you start your script from the gnuplot console you should add a `set output` at the end in order to close the file.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange As I understand, `rotate=90` is an option for pixel images from file, but not for rotating a graph of a function. I guess you have to modify your function and/or swap signs and/or swap `x(t)` and `y(t)`.

Comment: I just noticed the additional section - very nice rotations!